# How to set focus to a Control on the Form when cancelling FormClosing event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, event-handling, formclosing

I am validating input on textboxes on the FormClosing event of my Form and if the user decides to cancel closing, I set `e.Cancel = true` so as to stop the FormClosing event. I then try to set focus to the first textbox but this is not working.

```
private void AddDriver_Window_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this._Cancel(sender, e))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.textboxFirstName.Focus();
    }
}
```

If you are interested in seeing the `._Cancel` method I asked an unrelated question [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318314/why-is-my-formclosing-event-handler-throwing-a-stack-overflow-exception).

Comment: There's no conceivable reason this could fail, other than obvious stuff like the textbox being disabled and this silly _Cancel() method always returning *true*.  Read [http://sscce.com]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this one Check this is it work for you..

```
private void AddDriver_Window_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if( DialogResult.Cancel == MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit programm","Alert",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        textBox1.Focus();
    }
}
```

this will popup a message box and if click cancel then automatically focus on the textbox1.